# I need an example of CSS to use to change the sharepoint calendar event colors by category

Tags: calendar

I see references to CSS but nobody seems to have posted the code.

I was reading the post to change the default color, when I read that CSS can be used to change the colors by category field in the calendar.

Comment: You probably can't do that directly.  You will need to create views that filter by category, then create overlays based on those views. SharePoint will then put different CSS classes on the overlays, which correspond with your categories.  Then you can override those CSS classes to make things the color you want them to be.

Comment: I have used the calendar overlay and even customized the colors using CSS but I have over 100 views for this complex calendar and the view picker in the overlay won't show them all. Even if it did, I'd have to add that to every set of views I'm using. Thanks though.

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

What **version of SharePoint** are you using?

SharePoint 2010 and SharePoint 2013 include functionality that can be leveraged to achieve this effect, with no code needed. It may not be a completely obvious solution when working with a single Calendar, though. The secret lies in the use of the Calendar Overlay.

More information you can use the Blog

https://www.premierpointsolutions.com/training/help-and-how-to-articles/color-code-events-on-a-sharepoint-calendar/

Hope this helps, let us know.

Comment: I have used the calendar overlay and even customized the colors using CSS but I have over 100 views for this complex calendar and the view picker in the overlay won't show them all. Even if it did, I'd have to add that to every set of views I'm using. Thanks though.

Answer (score 1):

I used something similar to this. I couldn't find the bookmark for the code I used but this is very close.
http://www.sharepointjunkies.com/color-coded-calendar-sharepoint-online-using-javascript/

Found the one I used. https://blog.metrostarsystems.com/2014/07/16/sharepoint-2013-any-color-coded-calendar-step-by-step/

Comment: I can not get the one you used to work. It locks up the view page and I have to shut down to navigate anywhere.